# When is std::thread destructor called?

Tags: c++, stdthread

I know that `std::thread` destructors are called on main exit, or when a thread object goes out of scope.

But is it also destroyed when a function that it is calling is done executing?
If not what happens to such a thread, can I still `join()` it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But is it also destroyed when a function that it is calling is done executing? If not what happens to such a thread, can I still `join()` it?

No it isn't destroyed, but marked [`joinable()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable). So yes you can still `join()` it.

Otherwise as from the title of your question (*"When is std::thread destructor called?"*) and what you say in your post

> I know that std::thread destructors are called on main exit, or when a thread object goes out of scope.

It's like with any other instance: The destructor is called when the instance goes out of scope or `delete` is called in case the instances were allocated dynamically.

Here's a small example code

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void foo() {
    std::cout  << "Hello from thread!" << std::endl;
}

int main() { 
    std::thread t(foo);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    std::cout << "t.joinable() is " << t.joinable() << std::endl;
    t.join();
}
```

The output is

> ```
> Hello from thread!
> t.joinable() is 1
> ```

See it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73d8e840adcf35f0).